# Resolving using Autofac within an object

Tags: c#, autofac

I have something like the following class:

```
public class MessagePublisher : IMessagePublisher
{
    private readonly IComponentContext componentContext;

    public MessagePublisher(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        this.componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    public void PublishMessage<T>(T message) where T : class
    {
        var messageConsumers = componentContext.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMessageConsumer<T>>>();

        foreach (IMessageConsumer<T> messageConsumer in messageConsumers)
        {
            // Do some stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

}

This... doesn't work. I get an error from Autofac indicating I can't store the component context like I have, which makes sense.

> This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components from.

I totally get why this doesn't work. What I'm wondering is if there's an alternate way to do what I'm trying to do, which is to resolve a type within a method (I can't pass it in via the constructor, since I don't know the type at that point). Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess this is considered an anti-pattern to DI !?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it, but you must have the registration wrong. I'm guessing you have something like...

```
builder.Register(c => new MessagePublisher(c));
```

but you need to do

```
builder.Register(c => new MessagePublisher(c.Resolve<IComponentContext>()));
```

That being said, giving normal classes direct access to your DI bits is usually an anti-pattern, but sometimes some plumbing/framework code may need to do so.